# how to drop column which includes Nan value in data frame?

Tags: python, pandas, radio-button

I have a function that check which radio button is checked and based on the selected radio button

- by row
- by column

the system will drop the records that includes **Nan Values**

When the user select drop **by row** the function work and return the required result.

When the user select drop **by column** the function will crash and display the below error.

```
self.df= self.df.dropna(subset =item, axis= 1 , inplace=False)
  File "F:\AIenv\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\frame.py", line 4999, in dropna
    raise KeyError(list(np.compress(check, subset)))
```

**Code:**

```
def getText(self,df,item):
    if (len(item)>0):
        print(item)        
        if self.RD_row.isChecked()==True:
            print("RD_row")
            self.df= self.df.dropna(subset = item , inplace=False)
        elif self.RD_column.isChecked()==True:
            print("RD_column")
            self.df= self.df.dropna(subset =item, axis= 1 , inplace=False)
```

Comment: The `subset` parameter defines labels to look for in the other axis.  When axis is 1, it is looking for items in axis = 0. It doesn't exist hence the error. Remove that parameter and it will drop item columns

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution by using drop instead of dropna where the line it becomes :

```
self.df= self.df.drop(item, axis= 1 , inplace=False)
```

Comment: This will drop the column regardless of whether it contains NaN values or not? Is this what you want ?

Comment: @GhandiFloss your right now i try it and it drop the column whether it contains NaN OR Not   so how to drop the selected column that includes NaN

Comment: like I said in my comment above df.dropna(axis='columns') no subset paramter

Answer (score 0):

To drop rows that contain at least one NaN value, you can use

```py
df = df.dropna()
```

And to drop columns that contain at least one NaN value, you can use

```py
df = df.dropna(axis='columns')
```

To find out more about dealing with NaN values, you can checkout this [documentation](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html).

Comment: i tried to replace axis = 1 by axis = 'columns'  but the same error still showed

Comment: @Georges I think you should try `df = df.dropna(axis=1)`.